# weak optional variable showing nil even after assigning value?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a LoginCoordinator class whose start() method instantiates the LoginViewController. But even after assigning the coordinator variable in LoginViewController from LoginCoordinator, 'sometimes' the coordinator variable is nil in the view-controller.

By 'sometimes' I mean, when I debug and keep a breakpoint inside the start() method then, the value is assigned.

This is my LoginCoordinator

```
class LoginCoordinator: Coordinator {
var navigationController: UINavigationController
weak var parent: MainCoordinator?
var childCoordinators: [Coordinator]?


init(navController: UINavigationController) {
    self.navigationController = navController
}

func start() {
    let vc: LoginViewController = UIStoryboard.main.instantiateViewController()
    vc.coordinator = self
    navigationController.pushViewController(vc,animated: true)
}

func goToSignUp() {
    let signUpCoordinator = SignUpCoordinator(navController: navigationController)
    childCoordinators?.append(signUpCoordinator)
    signUpCoordinator.start()
}

func goToHomeVC() {
    let homeCoordinator = HomeCoordinator(navControl: navigationController)
    childCoordinators?.append(homeCoordinator)
    homeCoordinator.start()
 }
}
```

This is my LoginViewController

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak private var userName: HubTextField!
@IBOutlet weak private var password: HubTextField!
@IBOutlet weak private var forgotPassword: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var loginButton: HubButton!
var viewModel: LoginSignupVM = .init(totalItem: 2)
weak var coordinator: LoginCoordinator?

fileprivate func setupForgotPassword() {
    forgotPassword.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(forgotTapped))
    forgotPassword.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loginButton.appearance = Appearance(cornerRadius: loginButton.frame.height/2)
    loginButton.setTitle(TitleText.loginText, for: .normal)
    loginButton.isEnabled = false
    setupTextField()
    hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()
    setupForgotPassword()
    setupNavigationBar()
    
    // MARK: remove this later
    userName.text = "hirak@gmail.co"
    password.text = "asdfg123"
}

private func setupNavigationBar() {
    let titleView = UILabel(frame: .zero)
    titleView.text = "Login Up"
    titleView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
    rightButton()
}

fileprivate func rightButton() {
    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "signUp", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(goToSignUPScreen))
    rightButton.title = "sign Up"
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
}

@objc private func goToSignUPScreen() {
    coordinator?.goToSignUp()
}

@objc private func backButtonClicked() {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
}

@objc private func forgotTapped() {
    //MARK: todo forgot password
}

private func assignTags() {
    userName.tag = 0
    password.tag = 1
}

private func setupTextField() {
    userName.placeHolder = TitleText.email
    userName.textFieldType = .email
    userName.delegate = self
    password.placeHolder = TitleText.password
    password.textFieldType = .password
    password.delegate = self
    assignTags()
}

private func goToHomeViewController() {
    coordinator?.goToHomeVC()
}

@IBAction func onLoginClick(_ sender: Any) {
    //MARK: todo login click change hardcoded verification
    if let email = userName.text, let password = password.text {
        if email == "hirak@gmail.co" && password == "asdfg123" {
            goToHomeViewController()
        }
    }
  }
}

extension LoginViewController: ValidatorButton {
func addNewValidated(tag: Int, result: ValidationResult) {
    viewModel.validationList[tag] = result
    loginButton.isEnabled = viewModel.loginButtonEnabled()
   }
  }
```

LoginCoordinator is called from MainCoordinator as:

```
class MainCoordinator: Coordinator {
var isLogin: Bool = false
var navigationController: UINavigationController
var childCoordinators: [Coordinator]? = []
let window: UIWindow?

init(navController: UINavigationController, window: UIWindow) {
    self.navigationController = navController
    self.window = window
}

func start() {
    if isLogin {
       let child = HomeCoordinator(navControl: navigationController)
        childCoordinators?.append(child)
        child.start()
    } else {
    let child = LoginCoordinator(navController: 
navigationController)
        childCoordinators?.append(child)
        child.start()
    }
   } 
}
```

And MainCoordinator is called from sceneDelegate as follows:

```
   func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: 
UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: 
UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    guard let scene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene)
    self.window = window
    
    let navigationController = UINavigationController()
    let mainCoordinator = MainCoordinator(navController: 
  navigationController,window: window)
    mainCoordinator.start()
    window.rootViewController = navigationController
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
  }
```

Comment: assign value inside DispatchQueue.main.async block

Comment: Who holds a strong reference to the coordinator? Something needs to hold a strong reference to the coordinator for it not to be deallocated.

Comment: @Sweeper there is a different coordinator who holds a strong reference to LoginCoordinator.

Comment: @GopiDonga why so?

Comment: And who holds a strong reference to that? Try tracing the chain of references. Something is being deallocated, which causes the login coordinator to be deallocated, and you need to find that "something".

Comment: @Sweeper I have edited the code to give full view, can you check where it is deallocating?

Comment: Aha, I knew it! You declared `mainCoordinator` as a local variable, which will be _gone_ after the method in which it is declared finishes.

Comment: @HirakJBorah i totally missed the weak reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mainCoordinator` is declared as a local variable in the `willConnectTo` delegate method:

```
let mainCoordinator = MainCoordinator(navController: 
    navigationController,window: window)
```

This means that it can be deallocated after the last access to it in `willConnectTo`.

Since `mainCoordinator` holds the only strong reference to `LoginCoordinator`, it will be deallocated too. This is why you see `nil` in the view controller - at that point, `mainCoordinator` has been deallocated.

You still see a non-nil value in `LoginCoordinator.start`, because at that point `mainCoordinator.start` still hasn't finished, so `mainCoordinator` is not deallocated yet.

To solve this, you can either make the scene delegate hold a strong reference to the main coordinator, by declaring a property called `mainCoordinator`:

```
var mainCoordinator: MainCoordinator!

// in willConnectTo:
mainCoordinator = MainCoordinator(navController: 
    navigationController,window: window)
```

Comment: Actually `mainCoordinator` can be deallocated even before `willConnectTo` finishes running. Swift currently makes no guarantee about the lifetime of objects in their surrounding scope.

Comment: @Sulthan Oh I didn't know that! Edited. Is the wording better now?

Comment: @Sweeper thanks a lot, this is working fine, I never thought the problem can go this deep :D.

Comment: @Sweeper That was just nitpicking :) I think this is going to change soon anyway. I remember seeing a proposal on the forums.